# SSRS shared datasets missing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Source files for shared datasets are lost/missing.  Any way to generate these from the SSRS report definition that is referencing them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download them from the server again.

Go to you SSRS home page (Report Manager, or Web Portal as its known in later versions of SSRS).

You might need to show hidden items, then open the datasets folder and you will see your shared datasets.

Click the one you need and there are options to either download the *.rsd file or open it directly in Report Builder, either way you will have *.rsd file which you can either add back into your Visual Studio project or open in a text editor and get the command text.